# How to make feedly look better in Kubuntu Firefox like in Firefox in Windows?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, kde, fonts, web-feed

Here is the screenshot of feedly in Windows Firefox:
[image]

Screenshot of feedly in Kubuntu:
[image]

Also how can I make Kubuntu more polished? My current customization:

- Latte Dock
- Paprius Icon theme
- And Adapta kde for widgets

Please give me some suggestions regarding fonts, themes to make Kubuntu look more polished like Manjaro KDE or Pop OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing default fonts in firefox's settings to Liberation Serif:

[image]

Here is the new screenshot:

[image]

Tip:Don't bother installing Times New Roman font,Liberation font is perfect for linux and preinstalled.

[image]